# How do I use the tidyverse packages to get a running total of unique values occurring in a column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use the tidyverse (whatever package is appropriate) to add a column (via mutate()) that is a running total of the unique values that have occurred in the column so far. Here is some toy data, showing the desired output.

```r
data.frame("n"=c(1,1,1,6,7,8,8),"Unique cumsum"=c(1,1,1,2,3,4,4))
```

Who knows how to accomplish this in the tidyverse?

Comment: `data.table::rleid(x)` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `group_indices`

```
library(dplyr)
df1%>% 
     mutate(unique_cumsum = group_indices(., n))
#   n unique_cumsum
#1 1             1
#2 1             1
#3 1             1
#4 6             2
#5 7             3
#6 8             4
#7 8             4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame("n"=c(1,1,1,6,7,8,8))
```

Comment: This is another good option. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, using the fact that a `factor` will assign a sequential value to each unique item, and then converting the underlying factor codes with `as.numeric`:

```
data.frame("n"=c(1,1,1,6,7,8,8)) %>% mutate(unique_cumsum=as.numeric(factor(n)))
  n unique_cumsum
1 1             1
2 1             1
3 1             1
4 6             2
5 7             3
6 8             4
7 8             4
```

Comment: This is faster `match(n, unique(n))`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
df <- data.frame("n"=c(1,1,1,6,7,8,8))
df <- df %>% mutate(`unique cumsum` = cumsum(!duplicated(n)))
```

This should work even if your data is not sorted.